# Создание веб-скрейпера на node.js

Tags: node.js, веб-скрейпинг

Пишу скрейпер на node.js, запускается каждый вечер.

Он должен находить новые продукты на сайте-доноре (если можно так сказать) и добавлять их в БД.

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно будет сделать, если товаров около 30 тысяч? Т.е. на каждый товар нужно делать запрос в БД, чтобы посмотреть, есть ли такой товар?

Или правильнее будет сначала взять все товары из БД в массив, а потом искать в этом массиве, есть ли данный товар?

P.s. никакого API, RSS и т.д. у сайта нет, чтобы проверять время выкладывания товара, поэтому приходится проверять весь товар на сайте.

Comment: не понял немного. Если я ставлю уникальные поля в БД, то мне их не с чем сравнивать, как ни крути.

Comment: Описал в ответе более полно, с примером.

Answer (score 1):

Можно поставить уникальное поле и всегда добавлять записи, а исключение по `unique constraint exception` игнорировать. 
Таким образом вам скраппер будет работать быстрее и не нужны будут проверки.

Пример:

Есть таблица: `products (id, title, external_id, price)`

1) Ставите уникальный индекс (external_id).

Теперь при добавлении:

```
INSERT products (title, external_id) VALUES ("Test Product", 2);
```

если продукт со внешним ID = 2, т.е тот что на стороннем сайте существует в таблице, то база выдаст ошибку, ссылаясь на уникальность.

2) 
Если вы сами пишите запросы, то надо сделать `INSERT IGNORE`.

Если за вас делает ORMка, то ловите ошибку по типу unique constraint, ее игнорьте, 
остальные отдавайте выше (ибо замалчивать ошибки нельзя, в данном случаи исключение только по ошибке уникальности).